# Republishing a gem on RubyGems by replacing the whole gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently started a private gem (that I can guarantee noone else is using) to wrap a niche database's JDBC driver.  I ended up just publishing a version of the gem that I would like a do-over on.

I understand how to [yank](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem) a gem version, and the common solution of just bumping the version number and publishing that, which makes sense in most cases.  However, it's not so simple in my case as I would like to use the same gem version as the database driver I'm bundling (which seems to be a common practice), so bumping the version number isn't an option.  I also can't do something clever like adding a `.1` suffix to the database version number, as the database version has alphabet characters in it which make the `~>` operator unusable (all versions are seen as pre-releases).  In short, I **need** that exact version number.

My question is, if I yank **all versions** of the gem so that the gem name is available again in the RubyGems name pool, can I re-claim the gem name and push different code against the same gem versions I was using previously?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about matching the driver version to your gem version. Maybe major versions could match, but generally this is just going to cause you issues. What if you want to release outside of their release schedule? How do you tell users about breaking changes (normally major version increments)? It's always up to you, but I would avoid it.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a sticky issue.  The wrapper is dead simple (it actually just does `require`s to load up .jar files because the driver is proprietary), so once I'm ready to release to the public it shouldn't really need to change due to an emergency or anything like that.  Next time I will test more before publishing to RubyGems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace a gem, sorry. You must submit a new version.

Comment: My experiment seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

Preventing Gem modification is part of RubyGems.org design.  RubyGems on the users' computer will cache original gem files, so if you run `gem install` twice - the behavior might not be consistent if the original gem is modified on RubyGems.org, but the old version is kept in the cache.  Thus, the only thing you can do is `yank` or contact the RubyGems.org team to make an exception for you.

When we've done wrappers, like you suggested, we've added another `.1` suffix to differentiate different builds that wrap a certain version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if I yank **all versions** of the gem so that the gem name is available again in the RubyGems name pool

My answer seems to be off-topic, but in this case (**yank all versions of the gem**) it would be easier to remove the the old gem from RubyGems completely and publish all the versions to the new gem with same or slightly different name